# Downloading multiple .SAO files via http via Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, http

I need to use python3 to download multiple .SAO files from http.  Each file has a distinct url which differs by a number in the url (for example, https://www.1.SAO, https://www.2.SAO, etc.).  How do I achieve this, and how do I control where the files will be downloaded to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading a file is pretty simple using [wget](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget), and changing the URL can be done by modifying the string before executing the `download()` function.

to install wget, do `pip install wget` which will install wget to your default python instance. After that, just import it and you're good to go!

For example, if I wanted to download the .sao files from 1 to 10:

```
import wget
for i in range(1,11):
    url = "https://www.{0}.SAO".format(i) #adds the value of "i" in at "{0}"
    wget.download(url)
```

this will download all the files between `https://www.1.SAO` and `https://www.10.SAO` and save it to the working directory of the script.

If you wanted to change the directory, `wget.download()` has an optional second argument. For example, if I wanted to save my file to a directory called `downloads` which is located in the same directory as the script, I could call:

`wget.download(url,"downloads/")`

It would then save all my files in that subdirectory, instead of the working directory. If my directory is in an entire different part of the system (Let's say I wanted to download them to `/usr/bin/` or something, I can specify that as well, the same way as using a normal Unix file path:

`wget.download(url,"/usr/bin/")`

Hopefully this helps you get started.

Comment: When I run the code (using idle), it gives an error saying "no module named wget" , even though I installed wget to the same version of python that I am running with idle?

Comment: Make sure idle is executing the same version of python as you installed to. A lot of times, people will install both 2.7 and 3.x, and not realize that they installed a module to 2.7 when their environment is using 3.x